# How can I send an HTML form via email?

Tags: php, forms, email

Could someone tell me how does Google to send Poll form in an email

[image]

Seems that the source is base64 encoded but I dunno if it's possible, anyone here have any clue on how they do that?

Answer (score -1):

Use MIME Email type, it provides facility to add HTML tags in email.